# Randomly concatenate wav files in Matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, concatenation

I've just started learning to code for a few months, so I'm sorry if I'm not clear on how I ask my question:

I have different .wav files of synthesized syllables. I have to concatenate them randomly, but they can't be next to each other so they can't be immediately repeated one after another.

Right now I'm not even sure on how to do the first step which is reading the files. I used:

```
audios = dir('*.wav');
```

But with this, I'm having trouble extracting the syllables because they are saved in a struct array. So I tried:

```
samples = [1,.25*Fs]; 
[ba, fs]=audioread ('ba_2.wav',samples);
[bi, fs]=audioread ('bi_2.wav',samples);
[bo, fs]=audioread ('bo_2.wav',samples);
```

With all the 48 files (one by one), and I don't think this is efficient, but I read that using eval or a loop to assining names to variables is not a good idea. And by this way I can easily concatenate them like this:

```
p1=[ba;bi;bo];
```

But after this I'm stuck, because they have to be randomly repeated in a 2 minute loop. I don't know if maybe there's another way to save my syllables so I can better manipulate them, or what I must do.
I really appreciate your help, I haven't advanced in 2 weeks T-T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be an implementation. It, unfortunately, uses a loop that may or may not fit your needs. Within the loop, each audio file `.wav` is read and concatenated to a complete song called in this example `Audio_File`. The function `randperm()` is used to create a random array that can be used to index the structure and concatenate the audio files `.wav` in random order. In this example I use the variable `song` which can be representative of `syllable`.

### Method 1: Reading and Concatenating as a Single Audio Array

No regard to duration, only concatenates the `.wav` files randomly.

```
Audio_Info = dir('*.wav');
Number_Of_Audio_Files = length(Audio_Info);

%Creating a random array used for random indexing%
Random_Array = randperm(Number_Of_Audio_Files);

%Reading in the first song%
Audio_File = audioread(Audio_Info(Random_Array(1)).name);

for Index = 2: Number_Of_Audio_Files
    
Random_Index = Random_Array(Index);
%Reading in new song from structure%
Song = audioread(Audio_Info(Random_Index).name);

%Concantenating newly read song%
Audio_File = vertcat(Audio_File,Song);

end

%Playing back the audio%
Audio_Properties = audioinfo(Audio_Info(1).name);
Fs = Audio_Properties.SampleRate;
sound(Audio_File,Fs);
```

### Method 2: Reading Files and Playing within Loop for 2 Minutes

Plays `.wav` files for approximately 2 minutes randomly. Does not trim last `.wav` file played if it overflows 2 minutes. Any `.wav` file played will be executed before 2 minutes. This overflow scenario can be accommodated but depending on your length of the `.wav` files and your application this might not be crucial. The variable `Total_Duration` shown below is used to keep track of how long the audio has been playing. The function `audioinfo()` was used to retrieve the sampling frequency that is later used for playback.

```
Audio_Info = dir('*.wav');
Number_Of_Audio_Files = length(Audio_Info);

%Grabbing audio properties%
Audio_Properties = audioinfo(Audio_Info(1).name);
Fs = Audio_Properties.SampleRate;

Random_Index = 0;
Total_Duration = 0;
Duration_In_Seconds = 120;
while(Total_Duration < Duration_In_Seconds)
    
Random_Array = randperm(Number_Of_Audio_Files);
while(Random_Array(1) == Random_Index)
Random_Array = randperm(Number_Of_Audio_Files);
end
Random_Index = Random_Array(1);

%Reading in new song from structure%
Song = audioread(Audio_Info(Random_Index).name);
sound(Song,Fs);

Audio_Properties = audioinfo(Audio_Info(Random_Index).name);
Song_Duration = Audio_Properties.Duration;
Total_Duration = Total_Duration + Song_Duration;
pause(Song_Duration);
end
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I'm checking them, and they're already super useful :)  I'm understanding a lot better with this.

Comment: I'm glad. Your question was formulated very well!!! Feel free to ask about any details. :)